# System.WIndows.Application static members are thread safe?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, thread-safety

The Application static members are supposed to be thread safe:

> The public static (Shared in Visual
> Basic) members of this type are thread
> safe. In addition, the FindResource
> and TryFindResource methods and the
> Properties and Resources properties
> are thread safe.[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.aspx)

How much can we trust that statement in a multithreaded environment when calling static member methods of System.Windows.Application?

**Update:**
It's all in reference to this question: [Threading errors with Application.LoadComponent (key already exists)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463822/threading-errors-with-application-loadcomponent-key-already-exists/2463866#2463866)

I never thought I'd see a real bug in the library, but this must be the day for me... that question seems to show a genuine bug. Usually it's "user error," but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: I'd say that you can trust that statement as much as you can trust anything else in the documentation.  Is there something specific that you found to be untrue or have a question about?

Comment: @Jim http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463822/threading-errors-with-application-loadcomponent-key-already-exists/2463866#2463866

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the general pattern of the .Net framework and associated libraries.  Static / Shared members are assumed to be thread safe unless otherwise marked.  If you find a member that is not thread safe and is not marked as such in the documentation it is a bug (in either the documentation or implementation).

Therefore I think it's safe to rely on them being thread safe.

Comment: Yah, I think Kellls must have found a bug then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463822/threading-errors-with-application-loadcomponent-key-already-exists/2463866#2463866

Comment: @Lirik, in this case it does seem like there is a bug in one or the other.  I followed up on that thread to see if anyone filed a bug yet or not.  AFAIK, it's OK for that method to not be thread safe but if so the documentation should be updated.

Answer (score 1):

In general you should trust the documentation at first, but stop trusting it when things don't work as advertised.

In this case the documentation is wrong because of a bug in WPF.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463822/threading-errors-with-application-loadcomponent-key-already-exists/2464234#2464234) for details about the bug.

Comment: That's why I asked it :)... I'm the first person that answered that question.